# I want to display saxon errors in python

Tags: python-2.7, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using saxon xslt processor and python script to perform xslt transformations. I want to add exception handling to the python script. The saxon processor has inbuilt exceptions which are raised with codes (eg., SXXP003) etc. These error messages are displayed in the console because i am executing saxon files using batch file. The issue is that the saxon errors are not being written to traceback stack in python because of which i am unable to retrieve the error message. please provide a solution for the problem. I want to display the saxon error in the try except of python.

Regards
Anshul Mittal

Answer (score 1):

Python has a number of different ways of invoking external programs via their command line interface: check whether the method you are using has any way of redirecting the System.err output stream. (I don't know Python so I can't advise on that aspect). If you can find a way to do this, then you can try to parse the error messages and extract the error codes.

A different approach, which might perform better and would give you more control (but which might involve more effort to configure correctly), would be to use the new Saxon/C product and invoke it via its C APIs, instead of invoking the Java product via its command-line interface.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mike's reply, a python interface for Saxon/C is in development and worth a look:

https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon